NextJS 14 App Router - it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component
next : 14.2.1
react : 18.2.0
zustand : 4.5.2

Using custom look, I wanted to redirect to the login page if there was no specific string in Zustand.
// hooks/AdminCheck.ts

'use client'
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuthStore } from "../app/util/Zustand/store";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const useAdminCheck = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { authority } = useAuthStore((state) => ({
    authority: state.authority
  }))

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authority || (authority !== `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADMIN_PER}`)) {
      router.push("/auth/login");
    }
  }, [authority, router]);
};
export default useAdminCheck


NEXT_PUBLIC_ADMIN_PER has an administrator permission string.
//components/admin/Buttons.tsx
import useAdminCheck from "@/hooks/AdminCheck";
import { faUserPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export default function Buttons () {
    useAdminCheck()
    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 justify-items-center text-blue-500 w-1/2 border border-blue-500 m-2 gap-4">
            <section>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} className="px-1" />
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </section>

            <section>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} className="px-1" />
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </section>

            <section>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} className="px-1" />
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </section>

            <section>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} className="px-1" />
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

The error phrase below is output as the custom hook is imported from the required component.
Error: Attempted to call the default export of [project]/hooks/AdminCheck.ts from the server, but it's on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.
The same error message is output even if you import from inside the app directory.
//app/admin/page.tsx
import Buttons from "@/components/admin/Buttons";
import useAdminCheck from "@/hooks/AdminCheck";

// Admin Page

export default function page () {
    useAdminCheck()
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="text-2xl text-center text-blue-500 font-bold py-4">page</h1>

            <Buttons />
        </>
    )
}



It was confirmed that an error occurred when importing from inside the initial components directory.

The same error message occurred when importing inside the app directory.

Create-React-App (CRA) did not fail, but the problem occurred and the cause is unknown



Try adding 'use client' in Button.jsx, cause by default it's a server component, all hooks are client function, you can't access it on server.
Also, useRouter has been migrated, if you're using app router, you have to import it from next/navigation.
